# How to manage concurrent put and delete to Bigtable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I have Apache Beam pipeline that has two branches that will do IO to the same table of Bigtable. One will produce put mutations to Bigtable, second will produce delete mutations.

I can not find solution to solve race condition problem (for example I have two mutations - A (delete) and B (put), B needs to create column qualifier TEST and A needs to delete it, A becomes earlier then B and this can cause an issue).

I tried several approaches to solve such problem, but all of them are probabilistic and can cause leaving column qualifier forever in Bigtable.

Now I am thinking about the following architecture - I will keep those two branches with put and delete mutations and will allow to have such inconsistency in the table and will write batch job that will launch by schedule and to do recalculation of all values in column qualifiers.

I am thinking that it is pretty similar to lambda [architecture](https://databricks.com/glossary/lambda-architecture#:%7E:text=Lambda%20architecture%20is%20a%20way,methods%20with%20a%20hybrid%20approach.), right? And I am not sure that I will achieve strong data consistency in case of usage of streaming pipelines and some inconsistency is ok, right?

Comment: This sounds a bit like an XY problem instance - what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? ie. why do you have racing puts and deletes?

Comment: I have some logic to calculate column qualifiers from file. This file can be updated and each update of this file I need to calculate difference between new version and old. I need to update (put/delete) column qualifiers in Bigtable based on previous based on this difference.

Comment: File can be update in short period of time and I can have delete mutations before put mutation (because previous update of file can be in progress). I would like to know about reference about solving such sort of problems.

Comment: But aren't you going to get far more problems if updates from two file uploads race each other? Wouldn't it be better to serialize processing of the file, ie. you wait for the previous update to finish processing before you start the next?

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I wanted to get some ideas or best practices about such problems in case of absence of possibility to do it in another way. We have many clients that can send us such files and I designed it in another way - I decided to spawn new batch job for each file, but it can be costly (files can be send to us about 40 times per day and we have hundred clients). Streaming solution can be cheaper at first glance, because of I didn't figure out how to estimate costs for such approach (batch job per file) without actual implementation.

Comment: Conceptually, Bigtable is just storage, so if you need any sort of ordering enforcement, you have to do this manually. There are basically two ways: Mutual exclusion, so enforcing serialization of the processes writing data, or you can make the data idempotent/order-independent. The second approach is far more complex, as you have to come up with a data schema that encodes the sequencing and then you either periodically garbage collect old updates or you do it on the fly while reading. I think the first approach is much easier: Just throw the updates into a queue and have a single worker.

Comment: I am not sure that single worker can solve my problem because of events can received in different order from Pub/Sub (as I understand it doesn't guarantee that order of receiving records will be the same as order of sending records) and data volume is pretty big for one worker. I need to find scalable solution depends on data volume. What about garbage collecting? Do you mean to send put to BigTable and to do some garbage collection like periodical job that will make delete mutations in Bigtable, right?

Comment: So one thing you can do is take inspiration of log-structured storage and write your datapoints dated/serial numbered/however you can determine the order of files. Then, before consuming the data or while consuming, you "garbage collect" the old data and only read the most recent instance.
Also regarding scale: Don't underestimate what can be achieved even if moderately large instances. If the code is written well (ie. using connection pools, parallelized processing, leveraging ram instead of disk) you can easily achieve GB/s throughput.

Comment: To manage concurrent PUT and DELETE operations to Bigtable, it is important to use consistent row keys, consider using sharding, use the Mutation API for atomic updates, and use the official client libraries provided by Google.